# How do I get a listing of music files on a specific drive

Tags: windows-7, search, music, ipod, media

I'm helping someone setup their iPod, but they are using Windows 7, and I know XP. I don't see the music in the directory listing on his computer that I see on the iPod.

So I'm trying to search for all music files on the E: drive.  In Windows XP, this is easy.  Windows 7 has changed everything.  I googled this, and I found to type "music" in the Windows search bar.  This results in music "Libraries." Great.  There's still not a listing of the files.

I can search for *.wma, but that doesn't list all the music on the iPod.  There are many types of music files, but how do I get a list of *all* music files *just* on drive E:?  Again, on XP this was *very* easy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up "Computer" on the start menu.
2. Select your E:
3. In the top right corner of the window, there is a search box which is now set to only search E:

You might also want to search for *.mp3.  Or perhaps use iTunes to consolidate all music files into the iTunes Music folder.